# Code push return 400 error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, code-push

I use the MS CodePush to push react native code, but the log shows:

```
 [CodePush] 400: An update check must include a deployment key, and provide a semver compliant app version.
```

I have supplied the deployment key in Activity:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    // 4. Instantiate an instance of the CodePush runtime, using the right deployment key
    codePush = new CodePush("g-*********", this, BuildConfig.DEBUG);//staging

    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                    new MainReactPackage(), codePush.getReactPackage(), new RNPackage());
}
```

And set versionName in build.gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION as int
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22

        versionName "2.1.5"
        versionCode 35
        applicationId "com.xx"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PRINT_LOG", "true"
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_TYPE", '"dev"'
        #versionNameSuffix "_debug"  #[SOLVED]Here is the error goes! remove this line and it works!
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

and in JS:

```
 componentDidMount() {

//    codePush.sync();
    codePush.sync({ deploymentKey: "g-******************" });

  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Joachim Isaksson

Comment: Could you try logging `getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0).versionName`? What value do you see?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The version name is : 2.1.5_debug

Comment: "2.1.5_debug" is not a valid semver string, our server expects a valid semver such as "2.1.5". I see in your Gradle file that you have defined it as just "2.1.5", where does the "_debug" come from? Did you define it elsewhere e.g. in the "AndroidManifest.xml" file?

Comment: I set the version to 2.1.5 and it works! Thanks, Geoffrey, I own you a cup of coffee.

Comment: please answer this question below and I will accept it.

Comment: No probs! Thanks for using CodePush!! Feel free to ping me whenever you have questions, and raise issues on GitHub if you find that something is not working for you!

Comment: @GeoffreyGoh is this error harmful other than creating a little noise in the log? Is it OK if I intentionally set my version to an invalid semver to keep codepush out of my way while developing? I don't want it to apply an old update to my new stuff.

Comment: @chetstone Well, yes. You could also do wrap the call to `codePush.sync()` in `if (!__DEV__) { ... }` to make sure it only syncs up during production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"2.1.5_debug" is not a valid semver string, our server expects a valid semver such as "2.1.5".

I see in your Gradle file that you have defined it as just "2.1.5", where does the "_debug" come from? Did you define it elsewhere e.g. in the "AndroidManifest.xml" file?